# Using `find` to exclude multiple paths matching patterns

Tags: find

I'm trying to locate nested YAML and HTML files to replace a string with sed after creating the list; I'm not sure I fully understand how to use the `-prune` option, here's what I have:

```
find . -type f -name '*.yaml' -or -name '*.html' \
    -and -path './.git/*' -or -path '*/node_modules/*' -prune
```

For which I still get HTML files under `node_modules` directories

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you'd like to prune any directory called either `.git` or `node_modules` from the search tree, you would use

```
-type d \( -name .git -o -name node_modules \) -prune
```

This would cause `find` to not even enter these directories (the `-type d` is not strictly necessary, but I'll use it here for symmetry with `-type f`; see below).

Then you would add the other conditions,

```
-type d \( -name .git -o -name node_modules \) -prune -o \
-type f \( -name '*.yaml' -o -name '*.html' \) -print
```

Ending up with

```
find . \
    -type d \( -name .git -o -name node_modules \) -prune -o \
    -type f \( -name '*.yaml' -o -name '*.html' \) -print
```

Any action that you'd like to take on the pathnames that passes all tests should be done in place of the `-print`.

Note that the default logical operation between two predicates is `-a` (AND).

Comment: Thank you!, it indeed does work and the way that you construct the query makes sense

Answer (score 6):

```
man find
```

Is a great place to look for more info on find.

This should work for you.

```
find . \
    -type f \
    '(' -name '*.yaml' -or -name '*.html' ')' -and \
    -not '(' -path './.git/*' -or -path '*/node_modules/*' ')'
```

Note the use of parentheses, and the need to quote them due to their being intrinsic built-in syntax to bash (and most other shells).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did use the manual, however I found the `-prune` explanation and usage a bit confusing.